# Why do I get AttributeError: Canvas has no attribute acroForm?

Tags: python, pdf, attributeerror, reportlab

I am trying to create a PDF with an interactive form, using Reportlab. I followed several tutorials but I am always getting the same error. The line `form = c.acroForm` produces `AttributeError: 'Canvas' object has no attribute 'acroForm'`

Has anyone experienced the same problem and know how to solve it?

```py
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.pdfbase import pdfform

c = canvas.Canvas('my_form.pdf')

form = c.acroForm

c.save()
```

Comment: Does that pdf file contain a form?  If not, perhaps Canvas is smart enough not to create an acroForm attribute for pdfs which do not actually contain any forms?

Comment: `acroForm` or `acroform`?

Comment: @JohnGordon I don't think so, because it is supposed to create the PDF file...

Comment: @JacobIRR it should be ```acroForm``` (but I tried with both just in case, none are working)

Comment: Your code works for me. What ReportLab version are you using?

Comment: @MuriloSitonio I use reportlab version 3.3.0

Comment: @Sheltine try to uptade it (I'm using 3.5.21)

Comment: Okay thanks, I updated it. It works fine now (V. 3.5.23)